# Kafka connect sink connector with multiple one partitioned topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

We would like to use the Kafka connect sink connector in order to copy messages from Kafka to Mongo DB.
In our use case, we have multiple topics, with one partition each (the name of the topics can be regexed, for example, topic.XXX.name). The number of these topics is increasing continuously.
I wonder if the Kafka connect architecture fits this use case. If so, how can it be configured the gain high scaleability and parallelism? What will be the tasks.max? Number of workers?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect is flexible; the answer is as many as you need.

The number of running tasks per connect worker is mostly only limited by the JVM heap size of each worker. Adding more workers will allow you to have more total active connectors.

For sink connectors, however, you can only have as many total tasks as total topic partitions being consumed.

One thing to worry about, though, is frequent consumer group rebalancing as you add more and more topics. For this reason, it would be recommended to create independent connectors for any critical data

Comment: Thanks. So if I would like to scale my sink connector, what should I do? Increase task.max? Add more workers? Add more nodes? What would you do in my case in which the topics are consistently created? Last, what do you mean by "independent connectors for any critical data"?

Comment: You can do all the above. If you regex all topics into one connector, then if any single one of those topics fails to be read by the sink, then the entire sink connector can fail and stop without any notification... So "critical" meaning that you should isolate _important_ topics from others by running separate connectors for them

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer. We tested it, and as I said we have multiple topics with one partition each. we configured kafka connect sink connector (distributed mode) with 5 tasks max, and the cluster contains 5 pods. As it seems, all the traffic goes to one pod only. What can be the reason? Thanks

Comment: It's possible the advertised Connect http listeners aren't working, so only the leader gets all tasks, but I believe there is no guarantee that tasks are evenly distributed amongst connector tasks. If there is available resource in one instance, it can take them all

Comment: > As it seems, all the traffic goes to one pod only. What can be the reason? 
Have you found the reason of this? Sounds like it might be using the default RangeAssignor in `consumer.partition.assignment.strategy` property.